# How to know the release date of my BIOS version?

Tags: command-line

It's pretty easy to check the release date of BIOS version directly from the terminal emulator using a simple single command. So how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily use the command dmidecode.

First install if you haven't do yet:

```
sudo apt-get install dmidecode
```

Now to check the release date of BIOS easily run the command:

```
sudo dmidecode --string bios-release-date
```

The output will look like(my output):

```
07/23/2012
```

Answer (score 4):

`dmidecode` is indeed the easiest way but it should be used with caution. As mentioned at the end of `man dmidecode`:

```
BUGS
   More often than not, information contained in the DMI tables is inaccu‐
   rate, incomplete or simply wrong.
```

So, the authors themselves warn the user that the information returned might be crap.

Another program that is useful for getting information about the BIOS (though not the release date) is `biosdecode` which used to be part of `dmidecode` but has now been separated from it. Example output:

```
# biosdecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.6 present.
    Structure Table Length: 3650 bytes
    Structure Table Address: 0x000F2430
    Number Of Structures: 67
    Maximum Structure Size: 253 bytes
PCI Interrupt Routing 1.0 present.
    Router ID: 00:1f.0
    Exclusive IRQs: None
    Compatible Router: 8086:2912
    Slot Entry 1: ID 00:01, on-board
    Slot Entry 2: ID 00:02, on-board
    Slot Entry 3: ID 00:1f, on-board
    Slot Entry 4: ID 00:1d, on-board
    Slot Entry 5: ID 00:1a, on-board
    Slot Entry 6: ID 00:1b, on-board
    Slot Entry 7: ID 00:1c, on-board
    Slot Entry 8: ID 00:19, on-board
    Slot Entry 9: ID 02:00, slot number 33
    Slot Entry 10: ID 03:00, slot number 34
    Slot Entry 11: ID 04:00, slot number 8
    Slot Entry 12: ID 06:00, slot number 9
    Slot Entry 13: ID fe:00, slot number 10
    Slot Entry 14: ID fe:00, slot number 16
    Slot Entry 15: ID fe:00, slot number 17
    Slot Entry 16: ID 00:16, on-board
    Slot Entry 17: ID 0c:03, slot number 4
    Slot Entry 18: ID 0c:02, slot number 3
    Slot Entry 19: ID 0c:00, slot number 1
    Slot Entry 20: ID 0c:01, slot number 2
    Slot Entry 21: ID 0c:05, slot number 2
    Slot Entry 22: ID 00:03, on-board
    Slot Entry 23: ID 00:04, on-board
    Slot Entry 24: ID 00:05, on-board
    Slot Entry 25: ID 00:06, on-board
    Slot Entry 26: ID fe:00, slot number 1
    Slot Entry 27: ID fe:00, slot number 3
    Slot Entry 28: ID 00:00, on-board
PNP BIOS 1.0 present.
    Event Notification: Polling
    Event Notification Flag Address: 0x000004B4
    Real Mode 16-bit Code Address: F000:E2F1
    Real Mode 16-bit Data Address: 0040:0000
    16-bit Protected Mode Code Address: 0x0001D2F6
    16-bit Protected Mode Data Address: 0x00000400
ACPI 2.0 present.
    OEM Identifier: DELL  
    RSD Table 32-bit Address: 0xCF67DF18
    XSD Table 64-bit Address: 0x00000000CF67DE18
BIOS32 Service Directory present.
    Revision: 0
    Calling Interface Address: 0x000FFA10
```